# Urbanairship push working on some account not in some other

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, urbanairship.com

I am working on sending push notification using UrbanAirship service. I have created around 6 accounts . And I have followed the Urbanairship document. Among the 6 accounts 2 are pushing notification properly,others not **with the same code**.

I am getting 
"Application does not have permission to send to this device
Original Message: Error: mismatched sender ID"

But I had the project number entry in Airshipconfig.properties file.I have followed this [page too](https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/articles/823114-gcm-troubleshooting-guide) How can I come out from this error?

Note : I am using 45 days free trial version. Is there any limitation upon the free trail to send the push notification?

Need anymore details kindly let me know. Hardly seeking for the solution.

Comment: urbanairship support is pretty good in my experience, send them an email. I usually get a reply in a day or 2.

Comment: you've probably mixed your dev and prod accounts. UA Trial only offers development applications, so your GCM configuration will need to be development as well.